# "stripeErr : Error: You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, mern

I got this error while using stripe, on 23 feb 2022

Answer (score 0):

Check your account. You should provide a valid IEC export code to accept any payment.

Answer (score 0):

As per latest RBI guidelines, Stripe has switched from Charges API to Payment Intent API. Use below API as per data :

```
Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
  :customer => customer.id,
  :amount => params[:amount],
  :description => 'Rails Stripe transaction',
  :currency => 'usd',
)
```

It worked for me. Checkout Stripe API documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=ruby)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change "charges" to "paymentIntents"
example:

```
const payment  = await stripe.charges.create(  //Change here
  {
    amount: subTotal * 100,
    currency: "inr",
    customer: customer.id,
    receipt_email: token.email,
  },
  {
    idempotencyKey: uuidv4(),
  }
);
```